# Update Angular dynamic components through JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, angular5, angular-components

I am using angular 5 for my application and in my application I am creating various nested dynamic components and this nesting can go upto 4 levels. e.g.

```
<GP-Component>
    <parentCOmponent>
        <component>
            <sub-component></sub-component>
        </component>
    </parentCOmponent>
</GP-Component>
```

and in actual it looks like  :

```
<GP-Component>
<parentCOmponent>
    <component>
        <div>
            <div addSubComponent [config]="fewCOnfiguration"></div>
        </div>
    </component>

    //@ comp-2
    <component>
        <div>
            <div addSubComponent [config]="fewCOnfiguration"></div>
        </div>
    </component>

    //@ comp-3
    <component>
        <div >
            <div addSubComponent [config]="fewCOnfiguration"></div>
        </div>
    </component>

    //@ compo-4
    <component>
        <div>
            <div addSubComponent [config]="fewCOnfiguration"></div>
        </div>
    </component>

    //@ compo-5
    <component>
        <div>
            <div addSubComponent [config]="fewCOnfiguration"></div>
        </div>
    </component>
</parentCOmponent>
```

I maintain data through JSON, so when I initially pass JSON it creates everything on basis of properties defind in JSON, everything is working fine but now I am supposed to show user-B with updates after ceratin intervals when user-A is making changes.

**My question** is I can update JSON and that too at parent level but how with updated JSON I can show the changes because everything I created is dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the solution (thanks to one of my colleague) who was in my shoes few days back and I am writing answer If anyone looking something similar or If could improve it further.

Answer:

When I need to update data and to show it to user-B (sort of auto-update) on getting new data, I set new data into a service and :

```
this.ngOnDestroy();
//@ set data into a service
this.container.clear(); //@ container holding dynamic components
this.ngOnInit();
```

and It works fine. I am just worried that I am using polling to fetch data from server to show user-B update in every 10 seconds, so 6 times in a minute I will run `ngOnInit` cycle and I am not sure if this turns out to be costly execution because running `ngOnInit` will resets everything and all nested components will be re-initialised.

Looking forward if someone would suggest any better optimisation (other than reducing polling to 25-35 seconds)

Thanks